# Cordova: bad font-size

Tags: android, cordova, font-size

I write this code in HTML file:

```
<p style="font-size: 1px;">Little</p>
<p style="font-size: 6px;">Normal</p>
<p style="font-size: 11px;">Big</p>
<p style="font-size: 16px;">Very big</p>
```

In PC, we can't see "little" (too small), we can see "normal" but it's little and we can see "big" and "very big". That is normal.

The problem is in Cordova, the text "little" and "normal" display with the same size.

I noticed that the text which have a size under about 9px, display with a size of 9px.

Do you know this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This problem is related to the android browser itself, you can try to open that web page in the default web browser.

Adding `* {-webkit-text-size-adjust: none}` to your main ***css*** file can solve the problem in most versions of android.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this using CrossWalk, it even fixed some more rendering bugs that I wasn't noticing.

https://crosswalk-project.org/